# New PC won't restart

Tags: boot, bios, reboot

My new computer won't restart. There's no Windows installed, so there's also no software installed. Restart won't work if I try to restart from BIOS (save & restart) or neither when I push the restart button on the case. The PC tries to restart, but it slowly goes to sleep or something similar. The monitor goes to sleep and everything (coolers, etc.) seems to just run very slowly. Obviously no boot-up follows. The funny thing is, that when I "load optimal settings" in the BIOS, then the PC will restart for *one* time only.

So far I did a BIOS update, checked memory (Memtest86+) which seems fine. I really don't have any clues about what to do next.

Specs:

- CPU: i3-4150
- mobo: MSI Z87-G41 PC Mate
- GPU: none
- RAM: generic Corsair
- PSU: Corsair CX430
- SSD: Crucial MX100
- HDD: WD Black 1GB
- generic Samsung CD/DVD player

Comment: Verify all component and cable connections.

Comment: Done that. CPU and fans, PSU, SSD, HDD, DVD drive and front panel connected. Everything shows up as it should ...

Comment: If you disconnect the SSD, HDD and DVD drive does it still fail to restart?

Comment: Verify you have no bent pins.  If you have a single bent pin then that is likely the cause.

Comment: How did you run memtest?

Comment: Ultimate boot CD. When I tried now for a second time another test, memtest86, pc crashed...

Comment: Just a thought - Try taking mobo out of case and try and start it up (psu, CPU, 1 stick ram). Maybe place the mobo on it's cardboard box that it came in. This is just in case the wrong amount of stand offs where used and there is a short somewhere. If it still does not start, might be good to RMA the mobo. This is assuming you have checked for bent pins on the CPU and tried swapping each stick of ram in the test.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at other people's comments, here is my theory:

Its either that the hard drive is broken (or the DVD)

Or that its something messing around with the boot sector. Can you confirm that your PC passes POST. If it doesn't, can we get some sort of beep codes ?

If you go past POST, try to boot from a USB, to see where it goes.

Comment: I shouldnt have any power issues, I ran a calculation at some website for the build and it suggested max 186W, which CX430 should cover with no probs. There are no power problems otherwise as well.

Any ideas what to change in the BIOS power options?

Comment: @user220258 - His CPU has an `iGPU` there isn't a reason for him to use a `dGPU` at this point

Comment: Edited my comment based on your input.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove CMOS battery from motherboard
- If motherboard has a password reset jumper, put it in reset position.
- Wait 15 minutes.
- While waiting, remove all add-in hardware - remove any GPU, drives, or other PCIe cards.  Have no USB devices connected.  Use VGA or HDMI instead of DisplayPort monitor if possible.
- Replace CMOS battery and password reset jumper.
- Reset BIOS/UEFI settings to defaults.
- Power off system through button.  If it still happens at this point, it's a defective motherboard or firmware, or power supply.
- If it doesn't happen, add devices one-by-one until you isolate the issue.
- If a device causes the behavior to return, try in another computer.  If the device doesn't make the second computer do the same thing, you're back to a defective motherboard or power supply.

Answer (score -1):

From my experiences ,i would first try to reload os.and check condition of ssd,sometimes they last sometimes they dont.but if that doesnt work out loading os on ssd,then try loading on wd.Thats what i would try first.Ive beat my head against the wall for days on somethings that it was all os.

Comment: His system won't even POST.  This answer isn't that helpful.  It also contains considerable amounts of grammatical mistakes.

Comment: i was asumeing it made past post

Comment: I am offering feedback.  I am pointing out the problems that exist in the answer.  I encourage you to address those problems.  It seems like an answer that was published very quickly.  His computer is failing to POST consistently.  If you took offense then I apologize.  I mean he clearly indicate the system **doesn't even have an OS** at this point.

Comment: PC is brand new and one can not install windows if you cant restart (at least I cant). So its definitely not an OS problem .. thus I am afraid Ramhound has a point there ... but surely no offense meant.